# Elixir - merge list elements

Tags: elixir

I have a list

```
extensions = [
  [
    %{extension: "zip", size: 3627, type: "archives"},
    %{extension: "xml", size: 3627, type: "documents"}
  ],
  [
    %{extension: "png", size: 458605, type: "graphics"},
    %{extension: "png", size: 458605, type: "graphics"}
  ]
]
```

I need to merge list elements to get:

```
extensions = [
    %{extension: "zip", size: 3627, type: "archives"},
    %{extension: "xml", size: 3627, type: "documents"},
    %{extension: "png", size: 458605, type: "graphics"},
    %{extension: "png", size: 458605, type: "graphics"}
]
```

I can not find the right solution. I would be grateful for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`List.flatten/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/List.html#flatten/1):

```
iex> List.flatten(extensions)
[
  %{extension: "zip", size: 3627, type: "archives"},
  %{extension: "xml", size: 3627, type: "documents"},
  %{extension: "png", size: 458605, type: "graphics"},
  %{extension: "png", size: 458605, type: "graphics"}
]
```

Comment: Beware of using `List.flatten/1` when the lists to join might have _lists_ inside; it flattens deeply.

Answer (score 3):

While the answer provided by @Daniel is perfectly correct in this particular case, one needs to be cautious with `List.flatten/1`, since it **flattens deeply**. The precise answer to the question stated would be

```rb
extensions
|> :lists.reverse()
|> Enum.reduce(&++/2)
```

To understand the difference, let’s consider we have the following input.

```rb
#                         ⇓⇓⇓
extensions = [[1, 2], [3, [4]]]

List.flatten(extensions)
#⇒ [1, 2, 3, 4]

extensions |> :lists.reverse() |> Enum.reduce(&++/2)
#⇒ [1, 2, 3, [4]]
```

Comment: There's also `Enum.concat/1`.

Comment: @Dogbert indeed, but https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/v1.10.2/lib/elixir/lib/enum.ex#L577-L579 :))

Comment: That's `/2`, did you see `/1` above?

Comment: @Dogbert yes, it’s walking through all the elements which essentially copies the accumulator on each step. Of course, for tasks like that one, it’s nothing, but on huge lists, it might be a show-stopper.

Comment: @Dogbert I might be missing something, but my code, although walks through lists, copies the accumulator `N` times, where `N == length(input)`. `Enum.concat/1` copies the accumulator `M` times, where `M == length(result)`.

Comment: Seems like you're right. Tried a simple benchmark and your code is faster. +1